# Estimating mortality with acmeR package

Tags: hessian

There is a relatively new package that has come out called acmeR for producing estimates of mortality (for birds and bats), and it takes into consideration things like bleedthrough (was the carcass still there but undetected, and then found in a later search?), diminishing searcher efficiency, etc. This is extremely useful, except I can't seem to get it to work, despite it seeming to be pretty straightforward. The data structure should be like:

Date, in US format mm/dd/yyyy or ISO 8601 format yyyy-mm-dd
Time, in am/pm US format HH:MM:SS AM or 24-hr ISO format HH:MM:SS
ID, arbitrary distinct alpha strings unique to each carcas
Species, arbitrary distinct alpha strings (e.g. AOU, ABMP, IBP)
Event, “Place”, “Check”, or “Search” (only 1st letter counts)
Found, TRUE or FALSE (only 1st letter counts)

and look something like this: 
“Date”,“Time”,“ID”,“Species”,“Event”,“Found”

“1/7/2011”,“08:00:00 PM”,“T091”,“UNBA”,“Place”,TRUE

“1/8/2011”,“12:00:00 PM”,“T091”,“UNBA”,“Check”,TRUE

“1/8/2011”,“16:00:00 PM”,“T091”,“UNBA”,“Search”,FALSE

My data look like this:

- Date: Date, format: "2017-11-09" "2017-11-09" "2017-11-09" ...
- Time: Factor w/ 644 levels "1:00 PM","1:01 PM",..: 467 491 518 89 164 176 232 39 53 247 ...
- Species: Factor w/ 52 levels "AMCR","AMKE",..: 31 27 39 27 39 31 39 45 27 24 ...
- ID: Factor w/ 199 levels "GHBT001","GHBT002",..: 1 3 2 3 2 1 2 7 3 5 ...
- Event: Factor w/ 3 levels "Check","Place",..: 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 2 1 2 ...
- Found: logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE ...

I have played with the date, time, event, etc formats too, trying multiple formats because I have had some issues there. So here are some of the errors I have encountered, depending on what subset of data I use:

- Error in optim(p0, f, rd = rd, method = "BFGS", hessian = TRUE) :non-finite value supplied by optim In addition: Warning message: In log(c(a0, b0, t0)) : NaNs produced
- Error in read.data(fname, spec = spec, blind = blind) : Expecting date format YYYY-MM-DD (ISO) or MM/DD/YYYY (USA) USA
- Error in solve.default(rv$hessian): system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.57221e-20
- Warning message: # In sqrt(diag(Sig)[2]) : NaNs produced
- Error in solve.default(rv$hessian) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[2,2] = 0

The last error is most common (and note, my data are non-numeric, sooooo... I am not sure what math is being done behind the scenes to come up with these equations, then fail in the solve), but the others are persistent too. Sometimes, despite the formatting being exactly the same in one dataset, a subset of that data will return an error when the parent dataset does not (does not have anything to do with species being there/not being there in one or the other dataset, as far as I can tell).

I cannot find any bug reports or issues with the acmeR package out there - so maybe it runs perfectly and my data are the problem, but after three ecologists have vetted the data and pronounced it good, I am at a dead end.

Here is a subset of the data, so you can see what they look like:

- Date     Time Species      ID Event Found
- 8    2017-11-09  1:39 PM    VATH GHBT007     P     T
- 11   2017-11-09  2:26 PM    CORA GHBT004     P     T
- 12   2017-11-09  2:30 PM    EUST GHBT006     P     T
- 14   2017-11-09  6:43 AM    CORA GHBT004     S     T
- 18   2017-11-09  8:30 AM    EUST GHBT006     S     T
- 19   2017-11-09  9:40 AM    CORA GHBT004     C     T
- 20   2017-11-09 10:38 AM    EUST GHBT006     C     T
- 22   2017-11-09 11:27 AM    VATH GHBT007     S     F
- 32   2017-11-09 10:19 AM    EUST GHBT006     C     F

Comment: Data could use a little bit formatting. That way anyone who sees it could see it in a glance, rather than think what data this means

Comment: Thank you Syakur, will adjust.